# Create Custom Attribute Like "Extra Fee" in Category And Calculate It To grand Total

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, category-attribute, grand-total

I Have Created One Attribute In Category Like **Extra Fee**.
But How To Calculate That **Extra Fee** In Magento Grand Total ?

[image]

Comment: welcome to MSE.Please try something then we will help you to resolve the issue.... This question answer is too long.So try something